# I want my bootstrap 4 navbar to expand on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

This is my navbar code and i am using **bootstrap 4**. Any solution with either **javascript** or **jquery** will be useful. I want my navbar to expant on hovering hamburger icon.

```
    <div class="pos-f-t">
  <div class="collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
    <div class="bg-dark p-4">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Agency</a>
          </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Work</a>
          </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Careers</a>
          </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact US</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Add js files for `jQuery` and `Bootstrap`. That will work

Comment: yes i have added and linked them but how to activate that hover effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.navbar-toggler').mouseover(function() {
  if($('.collapse').css('display') == 'none')
            $('.collapse').show();
            else
             $('.collapse').hide();
        })
        });
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


   <div class="pos-f-t">
  <div class="collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
    <div class="bg-dark p-4">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Agency</a>
          </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Work</a>
          </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Careers</a>
          </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact US</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Make use of `show` class name. That will make it better.

Comment: insert jquery code inside snippet to see the result

Comment: I don't really think it's fair **to ask** for upvotes. Everyone can decide for themselves if an answer deserves an upvote.

Comment: @Klooven OP downvote becouse I use `.ccs(....)` and not `.show()` so i edited answer and ask for **him** to up again after edited

Comment: @AkashSalunkhe if it was helpfull please mark as answer

Answer (score 1):

Thats how i will do it

```js
$('.navbar-toggler').on('mouseenter', function(){
 $('.collapse').addClass('show');
});

$('.pos-f-t').on('mouseleave', function(){
 $('.collapse').removeClass('show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="pos-f-t">
  <div class="collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
    <div class="bg-dark p-4">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Agency</a>
          </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Work</a>
          </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Careers</a>
          </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact US</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better using ids to show and hide the nav:

```
$('.navbar-toggler').mouseenter(function()
 {
   $('#navbarToggleExternalContent').css("display")!="block"?
   $('#navbarToggleExternalContent').show():
   $('#navbarToggleExternalContent').hide()

});
```